# I have a problem with solving this recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm solving this recurrence relation:

$$
a(n+2)+4a(n+1)+4a(n)\;\; =\;\; 7
$$

where $n\geq 0, \; a(0) = 1$ and $a(1) = 2$.  My step is

1)solve for homogeneous solution
\begin{eqnarray*}
a(n+2)+4a(n+1)+4a(n)& = &0 \\
r^2+4r+4& = &0
\end{eqnarray*}

so $r=-2,-2$ and $a(n)=7(1^n)=7$.

2)particular solution
since 7 is just a constant, $a(n)=A$ for particular solution
so I should get

\begin{eqnarray*}
A(n+2)+4A(n+1)+4A& = &7\\
A(n)+2A+4A(n)+4A+4A & = &7\\
5A(n)+10A &= &7\\
\end{eqnarray*}

The problem is, I thought it should reduced nicely down to $A=$ constant but that $A(n)$ really disturbs me.. Did I do something wrong with my steps?

The answer to this problem is: $\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)(-2)^n - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)(n)(-2)^n + \left(\frac{7}{9}\right)$, with $n\geq 0$. I see that since there is a double root I have $(-2)^n$ twice in the answer but I'm not sure as to where $\frac{2}{9}$ and $\frac{5}{6}$ and $\frac{7}{9}$ came from..

Comment: The equation $r^2+4r+4=0$ has $-2$ as a double root. So the general solution of the homogeneous  equation is $A(-2)^n +Bn(-2)^n$. Your search for a particular solution yields $9\lambda=7$, so $\lambda=\frac{7}{9}$.

Comment: Thank you, how did u get 9λ=7? did I make algebra mistake in step 2? I really can't see where i'm making mistake but i think I'm making some algebra mistake

Comment: The recurrence is $a(n+2)+4a(n+1)+4a(n)=7$. You are looking for  particular solution, and have guessed (correctly) that $a(k)$ a constant $\lambda$ might work. Substituting we find that $a(n+2)=\lambda$, $a(n+1)=\lambda$, $a(n)=\lambda$, so $a(n+2)+4a(n+1)+4a(n)=9\lambda$. Set this equal to $7$. We get $\lambda=\frac{7}{9}$. Now the general solution is $\frac{7}{9}+A(-2)^n+Bn(-2)^n$. Evaluate at $n=0$ and $n=1$ to use your initial conditions and solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Your mistake is in for example thinking that $a(n+2)=an+2a$. Here $a(n+2)$ does not mean $a$ times $n+2$, it means the **function** $a(k)$ evaluated at $n+2$. I prefer writing $a_{n+2}$, $a_{n+1}$, $a_n$.

Comment: thank you so much, but i think I still don't get a(n+2)=λ, a(n+1)=λ, a(n)=λ, so a(n+2)+4a(n+1)+4a(n)=9λ part. I'm comparing this with textbook example and for a(n+2)-4a(n+1)+3a(n)=-200, where n is greater than or equal to 0, a(0)=3000, a(1)=3300, it leads to a(n+2)-4a(n+1)+3a(n)=-200, which simplifies to -2a=200 so a=100. To follow your argument isn't it supposed to lead to a(n+2)=λ, a(n+1)=λ, a(n)=λso a(n+2)-4a(n+1)+3a(n)=0λ and when I set it equal to -200, I get different answer than a=100. By the way, I'm not trying to argue with your answer, because I'm sure that they are correct :D.

Comment: The recurrence $a(n+2)-4a(n+1)+3a(n)=-200$ does not have a constant solution. Since you are not quoting the complete problem and solution, I do not know what you are referring to. Note by the way that putting $n=0$ in my general solution above, we get $\frac{7}{9}+A(-2)^0+B(0)(-2)^0=a(0)=1$, so $A=1-\frac{7}{9}=\frac{2}{9}$, which agrees with the $\frac{2}{9}$ in the answer you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution to such problem is given by using generating functions. Writing $a_n$ for the sequence, define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$. We write as follows, multiplying by $z^n$ and summing over $n \ge 0$, recognizing some sums:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n
    + 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
    + 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
    &= 7 \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \\
  \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2}
    + 4 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
    + 4 A(z)
    &= \frac{7}{1 - z}
\end{align*}$

Using the initial values, we can solve for $A(z)$:

$\begin{align*}
   A(z)
     &= \frac{1 + 5 z + z^2}{1 - 3 z - 4 z^3} \\
     &= \frac{7}{9 (1 - z)} - \frac{5}{6 (1 + 2 z)^2} + \frac{19}{18 (1 + 2 z)}
\end{align*}$

By the binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
  (1 + u)^{-m}
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-m}{n} u^n \\
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} u^n
\end{align*}$

you can read off coefficients:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= [z^n] A(z) \\
    &= \frac{7}{9}
        - \frac{5}{6} (-1)^n \binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} \cdot 2^n
        + \frac{19}{18} (-1)^n 2^n \\
   &= \frac{14 - (90 n + 71) \cdot (-2)^n}{18}
\end{align*}$